# Extraer selector de un XPath - Node JS Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, nodejs, puppeteer

mi consulta seria la siguiente, existe alguna forma de teniendo un xpath extraer o indicar cual seria el selector de ese xpath?
Se que se puede obtener el selector directamente desde la pagina, el problema es que ese selector es dinámico y varia dependiendo los perfiles a los que ingreso (facebook).
Mi consulta seria si teniendo el xpath completo del elemento de la pagina que necesito extraer, es posible obtener el selector? porque una vez teniendo el selector se lo pasaría por parámetro a una función la cual extrae el texto que contiene ese selector (ya sea innerText o outerText).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sí es posible, podrías utilizar esta librería que te convierte cualquier `xPath` a un string de tipo `selector` para una query

https://www.npmjs.com/package/xpath-to-selector

De todas formas si el selector es dinámico el xpath también será dinámico, es algo que tienes que tener en cuenta, así que si sabes que una clase o un id cambia con cada vista es mejor que intentes cambiar la estrategia para determinar el xpath o el selector, por ejemplo si tienes una estructura tipo

```html
<div id="abc">
    <span class="qwe"><i class="xyz">icon</i>
    <b class="jkl">Pepito Perez</b></span>
</div>
```

La mejor estrategia para obtener "Pepito Perez" sería a través de un selector de tipo

```
MEJOR:

div > span > b 

EVITAR:

.abc > .qwe > .jkl
```

En vez de algo que involucre clases o ID's que tiendan a cambiar